# Is there a way to backup an Amazon Fire tablet to Google cloud?

Tags: backup, google, cloud

I'm assuming I have to root the tablet and install and log into Google+ to be able to do this.  I want to backup an Amazon Fire tablet with all it's apps and data to Google cloud, then log into an Android tablet on that Google account, then access all the account settings, apps and data from the Amazon Fire tablet on the new Google tablet.

So I guess what I'm trying to do is migrate from an Amazon Fire tablet to an Android tablet as painlessly as possible.

Comment: Assuming your plan of a migration via backup works at all you should keep in mind that Google backup never backups the APK files, only the app package name. Thus if the app package names are different in Amazon and Google store this will not work. If the app signature key is different this should not work, too. Also some apps are by design bound to the device those apps will not work correctly even if backup and restore works in general (e.g. banking apps or other apps that use certain cryptography).